# Merge rows in SQL with specific logic

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

| ProductCategory | Qty | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Wood | 2 | 40 |
| Metal | 2 | 20 |
| Glass | 2 | 40 |
| Other | 2 | 30 |
| Misc | 3 | 10 |
| Extra | 5 | 20 |

I would like to merge Other, Misc and Extra categories as "Other" category. Qty and Price can have sum of Other, Misc and Extra categories.

| Product Category | Qty | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Wood | 2 | 40 |
| Metal | 2 | 20 |
| Glass | 2 | 40 |
| Extra | 10 (i.e. 2+3+5) | 60 (i.e. 30 + 10 + 20) |

One of the ways is to:

```
-- Create temp table to hold sum of Other, Misc, Extra

DECLARE @Qty AS INT, @Price AS INT

SELECT @Qty = Sum(Qty), @Price = Sum(Price) 
FROM Product 
WHERE ProductCategory IN ('Other', 'Extra', 'Misc')

DELETE FROM Product 
WHERE ProductCategory IN ('Other', 'Extra', 'Misc')

INSERT INTO Product (ProductCategory, Qty, Price) 
VALUES ('Extra', @Qty , @Price)
```

What is the easiest way to do this using SQL?

Comment: Two separarte queries you union seems like the most striaghtfoward way.  The first for all individual rows that get their own row, `select Product_category, Qty, Price from table where product_category not in ('other', 'misc', 'extra') union select 'Extra' as Product_category, SUM(Qty) as Qty, SUM(Price) as Price FROM table Where product_category IN ('other', 'misc', 'extra')`.  you might need a group by but I think this should be fine without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using a *case epxression* with `group by`

```
select v.ProductCategory, Sum(qty) Qty, Sum(price) Price
from t
cross apply (values(
    case when productcategory in ('Misc','Extra') then 'Other' /*or Extra...?*/
    else ProductCategory 
  end)
)v(ProductCategory)
group by v.ProductCategory
```

[Example fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5fcfe2ad4b8a5214306ecab4c60269e0)

Comment: You could put that expression in a `CROSS APPLY` which saves having to repeat it

Comment: Yes, Good idea thanks, will amend!

Answer (score 1):

Using an OUTPUT to a temp table

```
declare @tmp table(Qty int, Price int);

delete tbl
  output deleted.qty, deleted.price into @tmp (Qty, Price)
where ProductCategory in ('Misc','Other');

update t
  set Qty = t.Qty + u.qty , Price = t.Price + u.Price
from tbl t
join (select sum(Qty) qty, sum(Price) Price
      from @tmp) u
      on t.ProductCategory = 'Extra';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d226277f02ebcf4166dce5eaea036df2)